# Инструменты продуктивности для VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code, сниппет

Visual Studio 2015 из коробки содержит различные инструменты повышения производительности труда (да и просто резко повышающие удобство разработки): например, свободное выделение, закомментирование/раскомментирование выделенного текста, автозаполнение `for`, `foreach`, `switch` и т.п. - много всего.

Сейчас понадобилось поработать в VS Code, и остро захотелось функционала старшего брата. Есть ли какое-то расширение для Code, привносящее хотя бы часть подобного функционала? В гугле не нашёл, а как сформировать запрос в самом редакторе даже не знаю.

Comment: Да полно их там... Открой галерею расширений.

Comment: Да я-то открыл - неясно, что искать

Answer (score 2):

Может начать с предметной области? Какой язык, какие фреймверки?
Вот по ним и ищите.

***Мой набор (общие):***

- ***Spelling Checker for Visual Studio Code***
- Easy icons
- Git History (including git log)
- ***Trailing Spaces***

***Web:***

- vscode-stylelint
- ***PHP IntelliSense***
- ***PHP Debug Adapter for Visual Studio***
- Code Apache conf syntax support for VS Code

Comment: Спасибо, я уже освоился, хотя по прежнему очень не хватает свободного выделения